# Декоратор у неинициализированного объекта в Python

Tags: python, telebot, декоратор

У меня есть класс, в который я передаю некоторый токен, с помощью которого инициализируется объект телеграм бота. В этом же классе я применяю декораторы к некоторым функциям. Однако, при объявлении декоратора нужна ссылка на объект бота, который инициализируется только в конструкторе. В итоге, вылетает ошибка "NameError: name '_bot' is not defined"

Как мне передавать объект в класс и использовать его декораторы?

```
class Shop:

_bot:AsyncTeleBot

def __init__(self, token):
    self._token = token
    self._bot = AsyncTeleBot(token)

def start_bot(self):
    try:
        asyncio.run(self._bot.infinity_polling())
    except BaseException as ex: print(ex)

@_bot.message_handler(commands=['start']) //Вот здесь вылетает ошибка NameError: name '_bot' is not defined
async def start(self, message):
    await self._default_menu_handler.start_handler(message)
```

Comment: Собственно, а зачем вам классы?

Comment: Создавать несколько объектов бота с разными токенами